# Website Logo is overlapping on the Website Title

Tags: android, html, css

I want to seperate the website logo from the website title

[This is how the image looks when i open using Desktop version in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP4xx.jpg)

When i open with Normally in mobile. **The Website title and logo is Overlapping!!!**

[Mobile version overlapping picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMuZC.jpg)

The header.html page looks like this

```
    <!-- header 
   ================================================== -->
   <header class="short-header">   

    <div class="gradient-block"></div>  

    <div class="row header-content">
    <h1 align="center">  BRCB- Biology Resources for Curious Biologists</h1>
        <div class="logo"> 

             <a href="index.html">Author</a>

          </div>
```

CSS file is very big so please visit this [**github link**](https://github.com/gayathri-abhi/brcb.github.io/blob/master/css/main.css)

few lines of CSS page

```
/* ===================================================================
 *  09. header styles - (_layout.scss)
 *
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
header {
    width: 100%;
    background: #DBDBDB url(../images/escheresque_@2X.png) repeat;
    background-size: 46px 29px;
    height: 130px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
}
header .header-content {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 1290px;
    position: relative;
    top: 24px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
header a {
    border: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    header {
        height: 118px;
    }

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 * header logo - (_layout.css) 
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
header .logo {
    position: absolute;
    left: 35px;
    top: 6px;
    z-index: 601;
}

header .logo a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url("../images/logo.png") no-repeat center;
    background-size: 60px 60px;
    font: 0/0 a;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: transparent;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* responsive:
 * header logo
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    header .logo {
        left: 45px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    header .logo {
        left: 35px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    header .logo {
        left: 25px;
    }

    header .logo a {
        width: 54px;
        height: 54px;
        background-size: 54px 54px;
    }

}

/* ------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 * navigation - (_layout.css) 
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.triggers {
    position: absolute;
    right: 35px;
    top: 18px;
}

.triggers .search-trigger {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #000000;
}

.triggers .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
}

/* responsive:
 * triggers
 * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media only screen and (max-width:768px) {
    .triggers {
        right: 40px;
        top: 12px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .triggers {
        right: 30px;
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .triggers {
        right: 20px;
    }

}
```

[Index.html](https://github.com/gayathri-abhi/brcb.github.io/blob/master/index.html)

[header.html](https://github.com/gayathri-abhi/brcb.github.io/blob/master/header.html)

**Q1.I want both to use bigger font for BRCB and smaller font for Biological resources for curious biologists**

**Q2. Logo should not overlap with text**

Comment: Please create a minimal recreatable example. i.e. strip out everything but the most essential components and recreate the problem in a loadable snippet. Giving your whole code and expecting people to read it all isn't good edicate and very looked down on in this community likely to earn you significant downvotes.

Comment: Try creating a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).